# Excel File Not Downloading in a href - HTML

Tags: excel, html

I have an excel file that I'd like to download when users click on the href. I have the file path set but when I click on the link, nothing happens. I've never done this type of functionality before and am unsure what I'm missing or doing wrong.

```
  <li class="article-entry standard">
                        <h4><a href="C:\Users\avero\Documents\Finance Portal\Finance Portal\PDF File\Purchase Order Form.xlsx" download>Purchase Order</a></h4>

</li>
```

Comment: It should work fine. Check if your excel's url is correct.

Comment: I've updated the code. The path is correct but the excel file still doesn't download.